# Download link to a file using download attribute with anchor tag not working in chrome

Tags: html, download, anchor

I looked at many answers to this question , but none of the solutions solved my problem .

code :

```
<a target="_blank" href="file:///\\qctdfsrt\results\" download="Today's results">Download Results CSV</a>
```

This works fine in IE , but not in chrome . If I copy the link and paste in a new tab , it works , but clicking on the download button does not download the file .

Any suggestions or inputs are much appreciated .

Comment: You have to change permissions, in google chrome

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Elaborated!.Check it

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to google's settings.
2. Search for **Downloads**.
3. Click on site settings.
4. Click on *automatic downloads*.
5. Then add your site in that.

Comment: Thanks , but its still not working . If I load in new tab it shows "about:blank". But if I copy link address and paste in new tab , it downloads the file

Comment: when I tried inspect for html page , I have this error : Not allowed to load local resource:

Comment: Try to add `<a target=ABC download>`